# Django Custom User Model ForeignKey Addition Not Showing in Admin

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-admin

I've successfully created my own extension for the User model based on this tutorial:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-and-permissions

I also need to add a ForeignKey to a `Company` model, so that each user is assigned to a company. But this isn't showing in the admin at all, neither in the initial admin view or the edit view.

I've added the ForeignKey reference in the `MyUser` class like so:

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )

    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    company = models.ForeignKey('Company', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = MyUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['date_of_birth']

...
```

admin.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.forms import ReadOnlyPasswordHashField
from myapp.models import Company, Camera, MyUser

class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """A form for creating new users. Includes all the required
        fields, plus a repeated password."""
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ('email', 'date_of_birth', 'company')

    def clean_password2(self):
        # Check that the two password entries match
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Save the provided password in hashed format
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user

class UserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """A form for updating users. Includes all the fields on
        the user, but replaces the password field with admin's
        password hash display field.
        """
    password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField()

    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ('email', 'password', 'date_of_birth', 'company', 'is_active', 'is_admin')

    def clean_password(self):
        # Regardless of what the user provides, return the initial value.
        # This is done here, rather than on the field, because the
        # field does not have access to the initial value
        return self.initial["password"]

class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    # The forms to add and change user instances
    form = UserChangeForm
    add_form = UserCreationForm

    # The fields to be used in displaying the User model.
    # These override the definitions on the base UserAdmin
    # that reference specific fields on auth.User.
    list_display = ('email', 'date_of_birth', 'company', 'is_admin')
    list_filter = ('is_admin',)
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
        ('Personal info', {'fields': ('date_of_birth',)}),
        ('Company info', {'fields': ('company',)}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_admin',)}),
    )
    # add_fieldsets is not a standard ModelAdmin attribute. UserAdmin
    # overrides get_fieldsets to use this attribute when creating a user.
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'date_of_birth', 'password1', 'password2')}
        ),
    )
    search_fields = ('email',)
    ordering = ('email',)
    filter_horizontal = ()

admin.site.register(MyUser, UserAdmin)
admin.site.register(Company)
admin.site.register(Camera)

admin.site.unregister(Group)
```

Comment: Did you complete tutorial and added the admin registering and settings change? If yes, could you paste your admin.py code?

Comment: Yes, I did. I'll paste it above... I've tried adding reference to both `company` and `company_id` in the various places where fields are registered, to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a foreign key to a custom user model, you need just to specify it on the fieldsets attribute.

For example with this custom user in models.py:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    company = models.ForeignKey('Company', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

You need this in the admin.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserChangeForm
from myapp.models import CustomUser

class MyUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta(UserChangeForm.Meta):
        model = CustomUser

class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    form = MyUserChangeForm

    fieldsets = UserAdmin.fieldsets + (
        (None, {'fields': ('company')}),
    )


admin.site.register(CustomUser, MyUserAdmin)
```

Now you can select the user's company in the admin.

Comment: How do we override the createsuper command as CustomUser requires an company to be created.